# Scrapy: 0 pages scraped (works in scrapy shell but not with scrapy crawl spider command)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having some problems with scrapy. It's not returning any results. I have tried to copy and paste the following spider into the scrapy shell and it does work. Really not sure what the problem is, but when I run it with "scrapy crawl rxomega", it does not work.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from iherb.items import IherbItem

class RxomegaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'rxomega'
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.iherb.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://www.iherb.com/product-reviews/Natural-Factors-RxOmega-3-Factors-EPA-400-mg-DHA-200-mg-240-Softgels/4251/',
            'http://www.iherb.com/product-reviews/Now-Foods-Omega-3-Cardiovascular-Support-200-Softgels/323/']
    #rules = (
    #    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    #)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print('hello')
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[3]/div[2]/div')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            i = IherbItem()
            i['review'] = site.xpath('div[5]/p/text()').extract()
            items.append(i)
        return items
```

The message I see is...
scrapy crawl rxomega

```
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.22.0 started (bot: iherb)
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, django
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'iherb.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['iherb.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'iherb'}
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [rxomega] INFO: Spider opened
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [rxomega] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6026
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6083
2014-02-16 17:00:55-0800 [rxomega] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.iherb.com/product-reviews/Natural-Factors-RxOmega-3-Factors-EPA-400-mg-DHA-200-mg-240-Softgels/4251/> (referer: None)
2014-02-16 17:00:56-0800 [rxomega] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.iherb.com/product-reviews/Now-Foods-Omega-3-Cardiovascular-Support-200-Softgels/323/> (referer: None)
2014-02-16 17:00:56-0800 [rxomega] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-02-16 17:00:56-0800 [rxomega] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 588,
     'downloader/request_count': 2,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 37790,
     'downloader/response_count': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 17, 1, 0, 56, 22065),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'response_received_count': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 17, 1, 0, 55, 256404)}
2014-02-16 17:00:56-0800 [rxomega] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1):

The genspider feature creates a CrawlSpider, and parse_item, but the tutorial uses Spider, and parse. Both are versions 0.22. Change to Spider and parse for the above code and it works.

Comment: hi, would you mind giving a help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630771/scrapy-linkextractor-duplicating

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `CrawlerSpider` for scraping Items pages from that website, you'll have to change the following two:

1. `allowed_domains = ['www.iherb.com']` exclude http:// prefix
2. `rules = (
       Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'Items'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
   )`

expose rules and delete post `/` sign

Comment: 'www' is not part of domain, use only `allowed_domains = ['iherb.com']`

Answer (score 1):

Change the argument `CrawlSpider` in  `RxomegaSpider` class to `scrapy.Spider` and change function name from `parse_item` to `parse`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Spider and Parse like this :

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[3]/div[2]/div')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        i = IherbItem()
        i['review'] = site.xpath('div[5]/p/text()').extract()
        items.append(i)
    return items
```

Comment: If this is intended as a replacement for the questioners' parse_item() function, I'd suggest you edit your answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the start_requests method. It's always solved my problems in this situations :)  :

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://www.iherb.com/product-reviews/Natural-Factors-RxOmega-3-Factors-EPA-400-mg-DHA-200-mg-240-Softgels/4251/',
        'http://www.iherb.com/product-reviews/Now-Foods-Omega-3-Cardiovascular-Support-200-Softgels/323/',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse_item(self, response):
    print('hello')
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[3]/div[2]/div')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        i = IherbItem()
        i['review'] = site.xpath('div[5]/p/text()').extract()
        items.append(i)
    return items
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the
`allowed_domains` and use `def start_requests(self):`