# Scrapy not crawling

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I have my last question at here : [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648810/scrapy-start-crawling-after-login)

And now I have tried my best to think over and improve on my spider's structure.
however, due to some reason(s), my spider still did not manage to start crawling.

I have also checked xpath and they worked ( at chrome console).

I joined the url with the href because href always returns the parameter only. I have attached a sample link format at my last question. ( i want to keep this post awag from getting lengthy)

**My Spider:**

```
 class kmssSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='kmss'
    start_url = 'https://kmssqkr.hksarg/LotusQuickr/dept/Main.nsf/h_RoomHome/ade682e34fc59d274825770b0037d278/?OpenDocument#{unid=ADE682E34FC59D274825770B0037D278}'
    login_page = 'https://kmssqkr.hksarg/LotusQuickr/dept/Main.nsf?OpenDatabase&Login'
    allowed_domain = ["kmssqkr.hksarg"]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login ,dont_filter = True
                )
    def login(self,response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'user':'usename','password':'pw'},
                                        callback = self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self,response):
        if 'Welcome' in response.body:
            self.log("\n\n\n\n Successfuly Logged in \n\n\n ")
            yield Request(url=self.start_url,
                           cookies={'LtpaToken2':'jHxHvqs+NeT...'}
                                  )
        else:
            self.log("\n\n You are not logged in \n\n " )

    def parse(self,response):
        listattheleft = response.xpath("*//*[@class='qlist']/li[not(contains(@role,'menuitem'))]")
        anyfolder = response.xpath("*//*[@class='q-folderItem']/h4")
        anyfile = response.xpath("*//*[@class='q-otherItem']/h4")
        for each_tab in listattheleft:
            item = CrawlkmssItem()
            item['url'] = each_tab.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['title']   = each_tab.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            yield item

            if 'unid' not in each_tab.xpath('./a').extract():
                parameter = each_tab.xpath('a/@href').extract()
                locatetheroom = parameter.find('PageLibrary')
                item['room'] = parameter[locatetheroom:]
                locatethestart = response.url.find('#',0)
                full_url = response.url[:locatethestart] + parameter
                yield Request(url=full_url,
                              cookies={'LtpaToken2':'jHxHvqs+NeT...'}
                                  )

        for folder in anyfolder:
            folderparameter = folder.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            locatethestart = response.url.find('#',0)
            folder_url = response.url[:locatethestart]+ folderparameter
            yield Request(url=folder_url, callback='parse_folder',
                          cookies={'LtpaToken2':'jHxHvqs+NeT...'}
                                  )        

        for File in anyfile:
            fileparameter = File.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            locatethestart = response.url.find('#',0)
            file_url = response.url[:locatethestart] + fileparameter
            yield Request(url=file_url, callback='parse_file',
                          cookies={'LtpaToken2':'jHxHvqs+NeT...'}
                                  )  

    def parse_folder(self,response):
        findfolder = response.xpath("//div[@class='lotusHeader']")
        folderitem= CrawlkmssFolder()
        folderitem['foldername'] = findfolder.xpath('h1/span/span/text()').extract()
        folderitem['url']= response.url[response.url.find("unid=")+5:]    
        yield folderitem


    def parse_file(self,response):
        findfile = response.xpath("//div[@class='lotusContent']")
        fileitem = CrawlkmssFile()
        fileitem['filename']=findfile.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        fileitem['title']=findfile.xpath(".//div[@class='qkrTitle']/span/@title").extract()
        fileitem['author']=findfile.xpath(".//div[@class='lotusMeta']/span[3]/span/text()").extract()
        yield fileitem
```

The information I intended to crawl:

Left hand side bar:

[image]

Folder:

[image]

log:

```
c:\Users\~\crawlKMSS>scrapy crawl kmss
2015-07-28 17:54:59 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1 started (bot: crawlKMSS)
2015-07-28 17:54:59 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2015-07-28 17:54:59 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'crawlKMSS.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['crawlKMSS.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'crawlKMSS'}
2015-07-28 17:54:59 [py.warnings] WARNING: :0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'No module named service_identity'.  Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL to support it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.

2015-07-28 17:54:59 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-07-28 17:54:59 [boto] DEBUG: Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2015-07-28 17:55:00 [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yclam1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\yclam1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\yclam1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\yclam1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\yclam1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\yclam1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2015-07-28 17:55:00 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
2015-07-28 17:55:01 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpProxyMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-07-28 17:55:01 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-07-28 17:55:01 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-07-28 17:55:01 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-07-28 17:55:01 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-07-28 17:55:01 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-07-28 17:55:05 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kmssqkr.hksarg/LotusQuickr/dept/Main.nsf?OpenDatabase&Login> (referer: None)
2015-07-28 17:55:10 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://kmssqkr..hksarg/names.nsf?Login> (referer: https://kmssqkr.hksarg/LotusQuickr/dept/Main.nsf?OpenDatabase&Login)
2015-07-28 17:55:10 [kmss] DEBUG: 



 Successfuly Logged in 



2015-07-28 17:55:10 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kmssqkr.hksarg/LotusQuickr/dept/Main.nsf/h_RoomHome/ade682e34fc59d274825770b0037d278/?OpenDocument#%7Bunid=ADE682E34FC59D274825770B0037D278%7D> (referer: https://kmssqkr.hksarg/names.nsf?Login)
2015-07-28 17:55:10 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-07-28 17:55:10 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1636,
```

would Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating, why are you doing the heavy lifting job inheriting from the class `scrapy.Spider` when you have [`scrapy.Crawler`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider)? A `Spider` is normally used to scrape a list of pages, while a `Crawler` is used to crawl websites.

> This is the most commonly used spider for crawling regular websites, as it provides a convenient mechanism for following links by defining a set of rules.

Comment: I face a limitation of the knowledge on python and I do have difficulties in using crawlspider , esp when i need to extract item from multiple places in the website / it does not start crawling after log in

Answer (score 1):

There is a warning in your log and your traceback suggests that the error is raised at opening a `httpConnection`.

> 2015-07-28 17:54:59 [py.warnings] WARNING: :0: UserWarning: You do not
>   have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'No module
>   named service_identity'.  Please install it from
>   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity and make sure all of
>   its dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module
>   and a recent enough pyOpenSSL to support it, Twisted can perform only
>   rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid
>   certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.

Comment: It is quite tricky ( i think) because i have already intalled the latest version of service identity and pyopenssl. How should i tackle this error ?

Comment: The tricky thing is indeed to convince scrapy somehow that is must be wrong. Because scrapy tells you: **You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module** . Or to try to fix your setup what might be easier.